# twisted+gtk gui crashing very rarely

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, segmentation-fault, twisted

I'm using twisted with gtk (and gtk2reactor). My application crashes in a strange way. So far this is the second time it's crashed in this way. The previous time was about a month ago. These are the errors Python was able to capture in my log file:

```
2010-11-12 05:23:10,497 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkgc-win32.c:823: SaveDC failed: The operation completed successfully.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,499 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,500 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkgc-win32.c:963: RestoreDC failed: The operation completed successfully.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,503 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,515 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkdrawable-win32.c:1259: LineTo failed: The operation completed successfully.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,515 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,519 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkdrawable-win32.c:1800: GetDC failed: The operation completed successfully.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,519 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,519 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkgc-win32.c:961: GetCurrentObject failed: The handle is invalid.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,520 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,522 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkgc-win32.c:963: RestoreDC failed: The handle is invalid.
2010-11-12 05:23:10,523 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:10,523 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: _gdk_win32_drawable_release_dc: assertion `impl->hdc_count > 0' failed
2010-11-12 05:23:10,523 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:39,522 DEBUG    BHGUIController: Received message
2010-11-12 05:23:39,762 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: PangoWarning: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Segoe UI Bold 9'
2010-11-12 05:23:39,762 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:39,792 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkpixmap-win32.c:302: CreateDIBSection failed: The parameter is incorrect.
2010-11-12 05:23:39,792 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:39,792 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: gdkpixmap-win32.c:114: DeleteObject failed: The operation completed successfully.
2010-11-12 05:23:39,793 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
2010-11-12 05:23:39,793 ERROR    stderr: C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\gtk2reactor.py:255: GtkWarning: _gdk_drawable_ref_cairo_surface: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
2010-11-12 05:23:39,795 ERROR    stderr:   gtk.main()
```

Last time a similar series of errors appeared, followed by a segmentation fault. I can't be sure it was the same errors, but something along the lines.

I'm using Python 2.5.2, gtk 2.14.1, twisted 8.1.0 .

Answer (score 1):

These are all very old versions of the software involved.  Please upgrade to at least Python 2.6 and Twisted 10.1.  I am not sure what the status of GTK+ on Windows is, but I know that there were some bugfixes a couple of years ago, so you should upgrade that as much as possible too.

Comment: I've updated to Py 2.6, the latest Twisted and GTKs. Will see if the problem re-appears.